# How to classify nationality name on the bases of user driving license with tensor-flow keras python?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, tensorflow, cnn

I am new to deep learning. I want to create a classifier which can predict nationality names on the bases of nationality on driving license id.
To accomplish that, I created a data set of **USA** driving license images. Then created training data-set, labels and features of data and a classification model.

When I run my python script, the accuracy was 92%.
When I tested my model with different images it gave wrong result.

Python code like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import h5py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import pickle
import os
import cv2
import time

DATADIR = '/home/anupam/Documents/workspace/DjangoProject/DF-Web/datafornix/USADL_DATASET'


CATEGORIES = [

              'Alabma',
              'Connecticut',
               'California',
               'Delaware',
               'Georgia',
               'Indiana',
               'Louisiana',
               'Maine',
              'Massachusetts',
              'MaryLand',
             'NewHamshire',
              'NewJersey',
              'NewYork',
               'NewMexico',
              'Pennsylvania',
              'RohodeIsland',
              'Vermont',
              'Virginia',
        ]

encoder = LabelEncoder()
city_labels = encoder.fit_transform(CATEGORIES)
# print(city_labels)
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
city_labels = city_labels.reshape((18, 1))
state_array = encoder.fit_transform(city_labels)

training_data = []
IMG_SIZE = 200


def create_traing_dataset():
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            for x in state_array:
                try:
                    img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                    training_data.append([new_array, x])
                except Exception as e:
                    pass



create_traing_dataset()


#Randomize the dataset

import random

random.shuffle(training_data)

#Create a model
X = []
y = []

for features,label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)



X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)


pickle_out = open("X.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(X, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()


pickle_out = open("y.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(y, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()


pickle_in = open("X.pickle","rb")
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)

pickle_in = open("y.pickle","rb")
y = pickle.load(pickle_in)
y_data = []
for i in y:
    y_data.append(i[0])

y = np.array(y_data)
print(y)

X = X/255.0
print(X.size)
dense_layers = [0]
layer_sizes = [64]
conv_layers = [3]

for dense_layer in dense_layers:
    for layer_size in layer_sizes:
        for conv_layer in conv_layers:
            NAME = "{}-conv-{}-nodes-{}-dense-{}".format(conv_layer, layer_size, dense_layer, int(time.time()))
            print(NAME)

            model = Sequential()

            model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
            model.add(Activation('relu'))
            model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

            for l in range(conv_layer-1):
                model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3, 3)))
                model.add(Activation('relu'))
                model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

            model.add(Flatten())

            for _ in range(dense_layer):
                model.add(Dense(layer_size))
                model.add(Activation('relu'))

            model.add(Dense(1))
            model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

            tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(NAME))

            model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                          optimizer='adam',
                          metrics=['accuracy'],
                          )

            model.fit(X, y,
                      batch_size=32,
                      epochs=10,
                      validation_split=0.3,
                      callbacks=[tensorboard])

model.save('64x3-CNN.model')
```

And test classifier model like this:-

```
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("64x3-CNN.model")

CATEGORIES = [

              'Alabma',
              'Connecticut',
               'California',
               'Delaware',
               'Georgia',
               'Indiana',
               'Louisiana',
               'Maine',
              'Massachusetts',
              'MaryLand',
             'NewHamshire',
              'NewJersey',
              'NewYork',
               'NewMexico',
              'Pennsylvania',
              'RohodeIsland',
              'Vermont',
              'Virginia',
        ]



def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE = 200  # 50 in txt-based
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # read in the image, convert to grayscale
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))  # resize image to match model's expected sizing
    return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)  # return the image with shaping that TF wants.

prediction = model.predict([prepare('/home/anupam/Documents/workspace/DjangoProject/DF-Web/datafornix/download.jpeg')])  # REMEMBER YOU'RE PASSING A LIST OF THINGS YOU WISH TO PREDICT
print(prediction)
print(CATEGORIES[int(prediction[0][0])])
```

I think, I wrong with features and labels of training data set. If I wrong this. How I resolve that case??

What is the approach to find best result??

Please help to clear my above query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Inside for loops you are always creating a new model and then training it.

Afte the loops, you are saving the model. Meaning that you only save the last model which was in a variable `model`.

Also, you test your model only on one image. It's hard to say only on one image how good your model is. Test it on more images to check if it's good.

Comment: Hi Antonio, thanks for answering. Now I am saving model inside the first loop. Now accuracy comes on 96%. but when I test it, I got wrong result. I have only 1000 dl images dataset. So is it a reason of wrong result??